# Magento 2 Enable/Disable Module

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I installed a new extension on my site, but couldn't enable it.

ran command php bin/magento module:status
I can see it was enabled, but it's disabled on module manager.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then cleaned the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this

`php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Extension`

Although giving it more thought it might have disabled itself due to invalid key. Does have any kind of activation key?

If in doubt I would contact the extension developer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Module Entry in **setup_module** table

And run setup:upgrade